# want to display information with link to marker on map using gmaps4jsf

Tags: gmaps4jsf

I am using gmaps4jsf jar file and getting dynamic marker on google map. marker having some information and once i click on marker then get the popup and i wrote there "Click me!" i want to provide link on marker data

**jsf code:**

```
<m:map id="map" width="650px" height="450px" latitude="#{map.latitude}" longitude="#{map.longitude}" enableScrollWheelZoom="true" zoom="9">                   
    <m:marker latitude="#{point2.latitude}" longitude="#{point2.longitude}" >
       <m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Click me!" />
    </m:marker>                    
</m:map>

<p:column>
  <p:commandButton value="Display" action="#{map.display}" update="form"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: you mean you want to display information on marker and that information should be linkable?

Comment: Yes on marker showing "click me". i want to provide link only me not click, Is it possible?

Comment: I have a lots of solution using google api but i want to output through gmaps4jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to write somthing like this,

```
<m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Click <a href='info.xhtml' target='_blank'>me!</a>" />
```

**target='_blank'** means you link will be open in new tab if you want to open same tab then you can remove the target.

but in jsf you can't acheive symbol without & operater so you need to like this where  `&lt; means "<" and &gt means ">"`

```
<m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Click &lt;a href='info.xhtml' target='_blank'&gt;me!&lt;/a&gt;" />
```